# How to stop and reset my countdown timer?

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I'm trying to make my countdown timer do the following 4 things

1. When 'start' is clicked, change button to 'stop'
2. When 'stop' is clicked, stop the timer
3. When timer is stopped, show 'start' button
4. When 'reset' is clicked, reset the timer

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;
  var timeleft = 5;

  function nf(num) {
    var s = '0' + num;
    return s.slice(-2);
  }

  function convertSeconds(s) {
    var min = Math.floor(s / 60);
    var sec = s % 60;
    return nf(min, 2) + ' ' + nf(sec, 2);
  }

  function setup() {
    var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
    timer.innerHTML = (convertSeconds(timeleft - counter));

    var interval = setInterval(timeIt, 1000);

    function timeIt() {
      counter++;
      timer.innerHTML = (convertSeconds(timeleft - counter));
      if (counter == timeleft) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }
  }
  $("#timer-button").click(function() {
    setup();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there any relevant HTML you can post as well?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS and what the problem is. For example why not use jQuery all the way or not at all

Comment: Thanks! Here the HTML I have:

<body>
    <h1> flowcus </h1>
    <div class="background-color">
      <p id="timer">00 10</p>
      <div class="button-wrapper">
        <div id="timer-button" class="button">
          start
        </div>
        <div id="reset-button" class="button">
          reset
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

Comment: CSS: 

#timer {
    font-size:120px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-UltraLight', 'Helvetica Neue UltraLight', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

Answer (score 1):

I recently needed something like this too. I ended up writing an ES6 class for that.
In my solution, I used Events to notify other components about the timer. Here is a fiddle in which I met your needs, but I left my EventManager() calls to show what I actually did.
The used EventManager is [this one](https://github.com/gianmarcotoso/evnt). The timer counts in 100ms steps by default, but you can adjust this by calling startTimer() with the interval of choice.

```js
class Timer {
  constructor(maxTime, startValue = 0) {
    // Actual timer value 1/10s (100ms)
    this.value = startValue;
    // Maximum time of the timer in s
    this.maxTime = maxTime * 10;
    this.timerRunning = false;
  }

  /**
   * Starts the timer. Increments the timer value every 100ms.
   * @param {number} interval in ms
   */
  startTimer(interval = 100) {
    if (!this.timerRunning) {
      let parent = this;
      this.timerPointer = setInterval(function() {
        if (parent.value < parent.maxTime) {
          parent.value++;
          //EventManager.fire('timerUpdated');
          $("span").text(parent.value / 10 + "/" + parent.maxTime / 10);
        } else {
          parent.stopTimer();
          //EventManager.fire('timeExceeded');
          $("button").text("Start");
          this.resetTimer();
          $("span").text("Countdown over");
        }
      }, interval);
      this.timerRunning = true;
    }
  }

  // Stops the Timer.
  stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.timerPointer);
    this.timerRunning = false;
  }

  // Resets the timer and stops it.
  resetTimer() {
    this.stopTimer();
    this.value = 0;
    $("span").text("0/" + this.maxTime/10);
    //EventManager.fire('timerUpdated');
  }

  // Resets the timer and starts from the beginning.
  restartTimer() {
    this.resetTimer();
    this.startTimer();
  }
}

let timer = new Timer(6);
$("#start-stop").click(function() {
  if (timer.timerRunning) {
    timer.stopTimer();
    $("#start-stop").text("Start");
  } else {
    timer.startTimer();
    $("#start-stop").text("Stop");
  }
});
$("#reset").click(function() {
  timer.resetTimer();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start-stop">
Start
</button>
<button id="reset">
Reset
</button>
<span>Timer: </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const btn = document.querySelector('#timerBtn');
const resetbtn = document.querySelector('#reset');

let startFlag = 0;
let count = 0;
let intervalId;
const ms = 1000;

div.textContent = count;

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    startFlag = startFlag + 1;

    if(startFlag%2 !== 0) { // Start button clicked;
        btn.textContent = 'Stop';
        startTimer();
    } else {
        btn.textContent = 'Start';
        stopTimer();
    }
});

resetbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    count = 0;
    div.textContent = count;
});

function startTimer() {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        count = count + 1;
        div.textContent = count;
    }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<button id="timerBtn">Start</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```